# getVisibleRegion Coordinates Slightly Off

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am counting the number of visible markers on my map after a change in zoom using Android Google Maps v2.  First, I create the CameraPosition as follows:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(xx.xxxxxx, -xx.xxxxxx))
        .zoom((float) 14.3)
        .bearing(45)
        .tilt(45)
        .build();
```

Then I calculate the number of markers in the visible region using:

```
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {


            if (cameraPosition.zoom != priorZoom) {

                priorZoom = cameraPosition.zoom;
                LatLngBounds mLatLngBounds = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

                // get count of items in visible location

                // retrieve coordinates of all locations from database

                String[] selection = new String[] {String.valueOf(mLatLngBounds.southwest.latitude),
                        String.valueOf(mLatLngBounds.northeast.latitude),
                        String.valueOf(mLatLngBounds.southwest.longitude),
                        String.valueOf(mLatLngBounds.northeast.longitude)};

                Cursor cursor = readingDb.rawQuery("select count(*) from ZLOCATION where (ZLATITUDE BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (ZLONGITUDE BETWEEN ? AND ?)", selection);

                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int numVisible = cursor.getInt(0);

                cursor.close();

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "number visible markers is " + numVisible, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

While the number of markers shown approximates the actual number, I am finding that several more markers are counted than are displayed.  When I look at the coordinates of the markers that are included, but not displayed I am finding their actual latitude and longitude to be  included in the mLatLngBounds, but within .0001 of the border.

I'm guessing that the reported visible region is slightly greater than the actual.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that getVisibleRegion() returns incorrect coordinates too; in my case it's reporting a smaller rectangle vertically (i.e. approximately 6 minutes below the top edge) than is actually visible.

Not really an answer, but I've not got the reputation to comment!